# jQuery mobile - DOM Exception 18

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, mobile, jquery-mobile

I am trying to experiment with jQuery mobile, but can't seem to get started.

I have the following HMTL file hosted on a local server:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Which is causing

> Javascript error: undefined SECUIRTY_ERR: DOM Exception 18

when accessed from my iPhone from http://192.168.1.1:8000/mobile.html

Comment: Have you attempted to use Google? There seem to be some pretty good results: https://www.google.com/search?q=SECUIRTY_ERR%3A+DOM+Exception+18

Comment: Yes, but they're mostly about webkit notifications or local files.  I'm hoping someone familiar with jQuery mobile has some insight as to why I can't load the script.

Comment: The error you're getting is most likely related to the fact that you are testing on a local machine.

Answer (score 1):

Did you link the CSS stylesheet file as well before the jquery script include tags?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

Also, in order for the page to show, you must contain content into  containers like this:

```
<body>
  <div data-role='page'>
    <div data-role='header'>
    Header goes here
    </div>
    <div data-role='content'>
    Content goes here
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```